# Check if timeout occurred in ConditionVariable#wait

Tags: ruby, condition-variable

In ruby, when using `ConditionVariable#wait`, is there a way to tell if a timeout occurred?

`ConditionVariable#wait` can take a timeout as its second parameter. The documentation says:

> wait(mutex, timeout=nil)
>
> Releases the lock held in mutex and waits; reacquires the lock on wakeup.
>
> If timeout is given, this method returns after timeout seconds passed, even if no other thread doesn’t signal.

It doesn't look like there's anything that can tell me if a timeout occurred.

Here's an example where I need to know if there was a timeout.

Let's assume I have a condition variable synchronizing access to some shared resource. In one of my thread, I calling `#wait`. If there is no timeout, I am fine. I have the lock on the mutex associated with the condition variable and I can use the shared resource. If there is a timeout, I'm not guaranteed to have the lock on the mutex and I can't safely access the shared resource. I somehow need to be able to know if there was a timeout or not.

Comment: Why not to use mutex.owned? to check if you can access your resource?

Comment: You're probably mistaken what `ConditionVariable#wait` does. The `timeout` argument does not ensure thread would gain access back to *a shared resource* after it expires. It only means resource is unlocked for *other threads* at least for a `timeout` seconds. It's a way for mutex synchronization mechanism to leave more room for other threads.

Comment: @DavidUnric, I don't think the OP said that. He just wants to know if a timeout occurred. In fact, when wait returns, there is no guarantee that the thread that blocked on wait would have the resource - like if it was woken by a broadcast. In this case I might even want to know how much time elapsed before I was woken up, and wait again for the remaining time.